# Jewish people named the same as Jewish holidays

Tags: names, chagim-holidays

I know a few Jewish people with **first** names as *Yom Tov* and *Pesach*. Perhaps, *Shabbat* is used as a Jewish name, though I don't know anyone with that name. But I have not heard of anyone named *Shavu'ot*, *Succot*, *Roshashana*, *Chanukah* or *Purim*, etc.

Is there anything special about naming people after these two names that I mentioned? Is there any reason why the others might not have been used?

**Note**: I'm not seeking as much an answer to the 2nd question, as it may be as simple as "school kids might make fun of someone named Purim".

**Edited based on comments**

- 1st names only. I know that there's a lot more variance with last names, and, I have heard some strange ones, lately ;-)
- Names should clearly indicate the Yom Tov or occasion, itself. E.g. - someone named *Chag Hakatzir* would qualify, but not just *Katzir*.

(I know that one of Israel's former M.K.'s (I think?) has a last name "Katzir" but that doesn't qualify for 2 reasons.)

Comment: Shabbtai Tzvi? I can see why people might not use it as much anymore...Asif? Matan?

Comment: @Danno - I don't know anyone named "Asif", but that would work as it is a valid Torah-based name. "Matan" is too general, though. I know that you were referring to Shavuot, but the name "Matan" doesn't necessarily convey a holiday. For that matter, neither does "Asif", but it's mentioned in the Torah. I see that I may have to edit this question quite a bit.

Comment: for Matan I was think of matan torateinu and for Asif, I was thinking of Aasif Mandvi (the name Asif is used in Arabic-based names). The comment was meant more tongue in cheek...

Comment: ...my Dad used to address my siblings and I as "Tishabav" on occasion....

Comment: @Gary - I don't get it, unless the only occasion he did that was on 9 Av. My parents would occasionally call me names, but I don't think they called me a holiday.

Comment: @DanF - no, it was usually when we had done something he didn't approve of...implying we were little disasters.

Comment: Tongue in cheek, but this has an example (though it might be his last name, not sure): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezs5QvWBtf4

Comment: @Nic Oy, the cringe.

Comment: @DanF Does חגי qualify?  (חג)

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore See my response to Danno (2nd one). I would apply it to חגי as well. It doesn't refer to a specific holiday. It would be similar to the name *hadas* or *etrog*.