Why is Pesach/Paysach a name but no other holiday is?
Is there a reason that Pesach (usually Paysach when a person's name) is a relatively common Jewish name, whereas no other Yom Tov, specifically the other regalim, became names?

What? You never met Sukkos Goldstein?

Or Tuvia Shvat?

@RabbiKaii Chana Kay (that's probably actually a person)

The "Kievan Letter" has a Jew named Chanukkah.

duplicate of the following? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56824/jewish-people-named-the-same-as-jewish-holidays

Rabbi Yom Tov Ben Abraham

Rabbi Yom Tov Gaguin

@YDJ Nowadays too there are some bearers of that name: https://www.maariv.co.il/jewishism/holidays/Article-964961 says that in 2022 there were 186 people in Israel with the given name Chanukah.

https://forward.com/news/633231/shabbos-kestenbaum-republican-convention-antisemitism-harvard-democrat/?amp=1

This doesn't provide an answer, but my mother used to tease us kids by telling us about the time Pesach came on Purim.  (Of course, this referred to her cousin Pesach, who visited from "up state" on the holiday Purim. But she didn't let us know this explanation for a frustrating while.)
